# python vnv creation in docker container not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Python vnv (venv?) creation in docker container not working getting exceptions.

1. Does python3 have any support for vnv creation using local dependency?
2. How can we point dependency local folder using `requirement.txt` file?

Comment: "getting exceptions" - please include the full traceback in your post

Comment: 12/18/2019 01:47:01 AM Failed to created ENV error __exit____exit__